# Alsa driver only for amplifier /attenuator?

Tags: audio, alsa

Does ALSA have the concept of a driver *only* for an amplifier/attenuator?  I want to control my amplifier volume when I adjust system volume.  I could copy the current soundcard driver and add code to handle my amplifier, but I was hoping to avoid having to maintain the whole driver.

My hardware is set up like this:

```
Soundcard [analogue]-> Amplifier [analogue]-> Speaker
```

Alsa already handles the soundcard perfectly.  I have some code capable of controlling the gain of the amplifier directly; I want to use this rather than the sofware attenuator provided by the soundcard driver, ideally without having to fork the entire soundcard driver.

This isn't a Hi-fi application and I'm open to other ways of doing it if e.g. pulseaudio has the right concept.  I can already do this perfectly functionally from userspace (I have some fn `volume(unsigned char val)` which sets the volume correctly).

Is there some way of conceptually plumbing an amplifier/attenuator inline so that I only have to write an interface to my controlling code?

Answer (score 0):

That concept does exist.
It will however serve a very limited set of hardware devices.

[Here the code for TAS575xM based audio amps.](https:////www.spinics.net/lists/alsa-devel/msg136062.html)

[Here code & implementation details for SSM4567 based audio amps.](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/sound/ssm4567)

If you are looking for an ecosystem to invest your time in, then as you can deduce from the reading of above links, [I2C](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/index.html) would certainly candidate.

---

Nota : This list is non exhaustive of course. Only limited by my own knowledge)

And BTW, if there is no Alsa driver for your device, pulseaudio won't automagically invent / fake it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Both of these are i2c/i2s amplifiers which recieve pcm audio and send it straight to a speaker: in other words, they function as a very rudimentary soundcard with i2s drive.  What I'm looking for is where to put the code to control an amplifier in *series* with a (perfectly functional) soundcard output, so that the amplifier gain becomes in effect the soundcard mixer.

Comment: I've updated the question to be a lot more explicit.  The pulseaudio comment was merely to say that I want to do this with standard linux audio toolkits, so that applications manipulate the right volume natively: I guess it would be trivial with jack, but I was hoping to avoid that...

Comment: @2e0byo : "An amplifier in series with a soundcard output" What do you precisely mean ? The amplifier entry is connected to the analog output of your soundcard ? If so, then what are the other interfaces between your computer and the amplifier ?

Comment: @MC68080 exactly that: the amplifier analogue input comes from the soundcard analogue output.  I also have another connection between the computer and amplifier which controls the amplifier gain, and which I can control programmtically (the precise connection isn't important, but in one test setup it's actually a pwm output, smoothed, fed into a gain control pin.  In another I plan to build it will be an MCU pretending to be a rotary encoder.  The point is that I can call some fn and the volume at the speaker changes.  What I want to know is where to put that (working) fn.).

Comment: @2e0byo : Therefore would what you are looking for be more related to the implementation of a PWM driver ( https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/pwm.html ) than to whatever Alsa driver ?

Comment: No: I have successfully implemented a driver.  What I want to do is to implement a fader and attach it to a particular soundcard.  I can do that by simply modifying the current driver, but I'd like to it just by plugging in the fader.  The reason for asking about ALSA is that whilst I can already do this---nothing needs implementing, everything works---by simply overriding whatever fn my userspace program calls to set the volume, I want every volume setting command from every program to call my code, i.e. I want to implement a fader.  (1/2)

Comment: 2/2 this might be better off on SO, I was just wondering what bit of the alsa ecosystem (if any) corresponds to 'a device which changes the volume of an audio stream' without corresponding to 'a device *on this card* which changes the volume of an audio stream'.  In other words: whether ALSA (or anything else) has the concept of controlling an inline amp/attenuator/mixer *distinct* from awhatever is built into a particular soundcard, and attaching that to a particular sink.